# Can I call same RPC func in many servers at the same time?

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc, rpc

I try to find some fast algorithm of interprocess communication.
One of I need is an ability to send one command to multiple application instances at the same time. I had tried to find out for a day if I am able to start many instances of the same app (local-rpc-server-app) and call RPC from one client. I use `ncalrpc` protocol for this purpose.

I just want to start several instances of server and one instance if client, and then call the same RPC func one time on a client to evaluate this RPC func on every running server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either use multiple client threads (each making a separate server call) or modify the .acf and mark the call with the [async] attribute. If you go the latter route you can then make multiple calls on a single client thread. Note that asynchronous RPC is a fair bit more complicated than synchronous RPC due to needing to deal with call completions.

Making calls to multiple server instances (even local instances) is also made more complicated by the fact that you will have to somehow discover those endpoints, and the RPC namespace functions (RpcNs*) are no longer available as of Windows Vista.

Comment: I do not understand how to bind to multiply instances (different processes) of the same server without specifying it's endpoint name

Comment: Oh, I found - with MS example named DYNEPT.